# File::Find::Rule::LibMagic: Is it ok to keep options with undefined values?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, optional-parameters, file-find

Is it OK to keep options with undefined values (in this case 'maxdepth')?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use File::Find::Rule::LibMagic qw(find);
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $max_depth;
GetOptions ( 'max-depth=i' => \$max_depth );
my $dir = shift;

my @dbs = find( file => magic => 'SQLite*', maxdepth => $max_depth, in => $dir );
say for @dbs;
```

Or should I write it like this:

```
if ( defined $max_depth ) {
    @dbs = find( file => magic => 'SQLite*', maxdepth => $max_depth, in => $dir );
} else {
    @dbs = find( file => magic => 'SQLite*', in => $dir );
}
```

Comment: This question is about [File::Find::Rule::LibMagic](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find::Rule::LibMagic). This should appear more clearly in the title.

Comment: I added `File::Find::Rule::LibMagic` in the title. But my interest was more general - but maybe it is different from module to module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no problem in having `maxdepth` set to `undef` by using a variable with `undef` as its value. Every variable in Perl starts out with the `undef` value.

#### More Details

[`File::Find::Rule::LibMagic`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule%3a%3aLibMagic) extends [`File::Find::Rule`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule). The [`find`](https://metacpan.org/source/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm#L59) function in [`File::Find::Rule`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) starts with:

```
sub find {
    my $object = __PACKAGE__->new();
```

The [`new`](https://metacpan.org/source/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm#L102) functions returns:

```
bless {
    rules    => [],
    subs     => {},
    iterator => [],
    extras   => {},
    maxdepth => undef,
    mindepth => undef,
}, $class;
```

Note that `maxdepth` by default is set to `undef`.

Answer (score 1):

OK? It probably won't confuse File::Find::Rule

```
$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -le " print for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(undef)->in( q/tope/ ) "
tope
tope/a
tope/b
tope/c
tope/c/0
tope/c/1
tope/c/2

$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -le " print for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->in( q/tope/ ) "
tope
tope/a
tope/b
tope/c

$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -le " print for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(-1)->in( q/tope/ ) "
tope

$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -le " print for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(2)->in( q/tope/ ) "
tope
tope/a
tope/b
tope/c
tope/c/0
tope/c/1
tope/c/2

$ pmvers File::Find::Rule
0.33
```